# trying to convert xls to google spreadsheet using google app script and getting "Empty response" error

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drive

I'm trying to convert a xls file to a google spreadsheet with the following code:

```
  var searchFor ="fullText contains 'theFile.xls' and '" + FolderId + "' in parents";  
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor); 
  var file = files.next().getBlob();  
  var convertedFileinfo = {
    title: 'theFile',
    parents:[{id: FolderId}]
  };
  Drive.Files.insert(convertedFileinfo, file, {
    convert: true,
    uploadType:'resumable'
  })
```

But i'm getting "Empty response" error on Drive.Files.insert line...

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get it to work using copy:

```
  var searchFor ="fullText contains 'theFile.xls' and '" + FolderId + "' in parents"; 
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor); 
  var xlsFile = files.next();    
  Drive.Files.copy({}, xlsFile.getId(), {convert: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about following change?

**From :**

```
Drive.Files.insert(convertedFileinfo, file, {
  convert: true,
  uploadType:'resumable'
})
```

**To :**

```
Drive.Files.insert(convertedFileinfo, file, {
  convert: true
})
```

Comment: @Luis Gómez Guzmán In my environment, it works fine. Can you confirm whether it enabled Drive API at [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) and Google API console? If also this has already been done, I'm sorry.

Comment: yes to all, i added the `uploadType:'resumable'` parameter because the xls file has about 26 Mb. It works with files of about 5 Mb...

Comment: @Luis Gómez Guzmán In my environment, about 5.4MB was the limit to convert from xls to spreadsheet for Drive API v2 and v3. I'm sorry I couldn't be helpful for you.