# upload a file to Drive larger that 10 Mb using URLFetch POST with google app script

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, urlfetch

I'm trying to convert a xls file already in my drive to a spreadsheet, using google app scripts.

My first failed attempt using Drive.Files.insert is described here: 
[excel2sheet usind Drive.Files.insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318810/trying-to-convert-xls-to-google-spreadsheet-using-google-app-script-and-getting/44318951?noredirect=1#comment75645236_44318951)
If you can help with that, you are welcome...

Looking around, I found a script that is supposed to work:
[convertExcel2Sheets](https://gist.github.com/azadisaryev/ab57e95096203edc2741)
but uses URLFetch POST to upload the file and my file is aprox. 26 Mb, so i get a "Limit Exceeded: URLFetch POST size" (since maximum size is 10 Mb)

I also tried changing the upload type on above script to `resumable` and method to `put`, but it didin't worked.

So my question is, is there a way to upload the file?

maybe trying to split (or simulate a split) the xls file...

Or is there another way to convert the file to a google spreadhsheet???

BTW, the file has only 1 page, but is huge...

Comment: Can you just put it in your local google directory and let google sync do it for you?

Comment: i don't use google drive for pc...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are hitting some limit with your spreadsheet,, see this page to get info about all limits that exist in Google Sheets,, forum post Q & A below is solution that I guess is similar to that you have

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/tgJ_t_2vEP4;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/functions$20for$20external$20reference

something below lines:

```
Number of Cells: Total of 400,000 cells across all sheets
Number of Columns: 256 columns per sheet
Number of Formulas: 40,000 cells containing formulas
Number of Tabs: 200 sheets per workbook
GoogleFinance formulas: 1,000 GoogleFinance formulas
ImportRange formulas: 50 cross-workbook reference formulas
ImportData, ImportHtml, ImportFeed, or ImportXml formulas: 50 functions for external data
Complexity: VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP formulas tend to be more complex than other functions, and may slow down your spreadsheet. After getting data points through VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP, try re-pasting them as "values only" to reduce spreadsheet size
```

this is the page from official Google Help page:

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en&vid=0-541211794164-1496437185402

Comment: hi, the limit is the file size. For "post", 10Mb is the limit, and my file has 26 Mb. That's why i'm asking if there is a way to update the file in parts...